# Create custom aegir signup form

Tags: drupal, hosting, provisioning

I want to create a custom sign up form for the aegir provisioning system in drupal and once the user fills out the form and submits, I want the website to be created on the domain name specified in the form and all other hooks that aegir executes while creating a website. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work out of the box.

If not, then the heavy-weight solution is to install [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) and the [Aegir-Ubercart integration module](http://drupal.org/project/uc_hosting), in addition to Aegir. Then you have to setup an appropiate product cart, with hosting features to each products, allowing automatic site creation.